# MongoDB query is not returning documents though it exists when querying an array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a list of documents in a collection that has the following structure

```
{
    "_id" : "5f341c57b156dd2fa020",
    "currentAddress" : {
        "address" : "Some number, some address",
        "country" : "ABC",
        "state" : "PQR",
        "city" : "ABCD",
        "landmark" : ""
    },
    "languages" : [ 
       "5d7f2536911a2e57b25b", 
       "5dfdf059fb595309c261"
    ]
    "service" : "5dfdc486c15893250df1",
    "specialSkills" : [ 
        "5edf9423eab473331fec"
    ],
    "gender" : "5dfcaaaf03f86917017",
    "agencyId" : "5f0d76de623bef03f1e",
    "firstName" : "John",
    "lastName" : "Doe",
    "dob" : ISODate("1991-06-12T18:30:00.000Z"),
    "age" : 29
}
```

This is my query

```
async.waterfall([
   (callback) => {
       userSchema.find({
          "currentAddress.city": "ABCD",
          "gender": "5dfcaaaf03f86917017",
          "age": {
              "$lte": 30,
              "$gte": 20
           },
           "languages": {
               "$in": [
                 "5d7f2536911a2e57b25b",
                  "5dfdf059fb595309c261"
                ]
            },
            "service": {
               "$in": [
                  "5dfdc486c15893250df1"
                ]
             },
            "agencyId": "5f0d76de623bef03f1e",
             "specialSkills": {
                "$in": [
                   "5edf9423eab473331fec"
                ]
              }
       }, (err, userInfo) => {
           callback(err, userInfo)
       })
   }
],(err, userInfo) => {
   res.json({
     err: err,
     userInfo: userInfo
   })
})
```

It works perfectly and returns the document when I pass all the key-value pairs, except when I pass the key-value for "**specialSkills**", the document is not returned and all that is returned is an empty array. I am stumped as to what is going wrong, I have been at it for hours but couldn't figure it out. Any help is really appreciated. Thanks.

P.S - I tested the query in Robo3T and it works perfectly fine. When I call it inside a function it isn't returning the document.

P.P.S - I have implemented this function inside waterfall model, hence I have tagged node.js in the question

Comment: try using `$all` instead of `$in`

Comment: @turivishal it didn't work.

Comment: it is working perfectly [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/exfDLE6bRHd) you just need to check object id of other field conditions, i have removed object ids from document in playground.

Comment: I know, I already tested it in mongo playground, I also tested it in Robo3T and the query works fine there as well. It isn't working when I execute it in the function call, that's why I mentioned I am stumped.

Comment: if query is working then you need to add your code, how we will know without checking implementation?

Comment: I have edited my question, please have a look. Hope it gives a bit more clarity on implementation.

Comment: Remove all fields that are not relevant from your question.

Comment: I added others to show that, when I pass those it works. If you see languages and special skills don't have much difference but the key-value pair for languages works but for special skills it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing `String` comparison.

`"service" : ObjectId("5dfdc486c15893250df1")` it is of `ObjectId` type. But query contains

```
 "service": {
       "$in": [
           "5dfdc486c15893250df1"
        ]
    }
```

You need to replace the above to

```
 "service": {
       "$in": [
           ObjectId("5dfdc486c15893250df1")
        ]
    }
```

Same applicable to the other fields also.

Comment: the problem isn't with the key-value pair "service". I have mentioned in my question that ALL key-value pairs return the document except when the key-value pair "specialSkills" is passed. Pardon me as I copied the document directly from Robo3T hence the ObjectId() was present. I have edited my question.